# what's "disruption" globally mean today?

Tags: pejorative-language, business-language, language-evolution

The word "disruption" doesn't have the same meaning, also totally different when used in business context.

Someone can help define it better?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have the same meaning as *what*?  Define it better than what?

Comment: Can you define what you mean?

Comment: It's likely you're referring to the buzzword 'disrupt' that is often applied to technology. It's rubbish, I work in the sector, if I had my way in the studio the word would be banned in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dictionary.com, **disruption** can mean:

1. forcible separation or division into parts.
2. a disrupted condition:
   *After the coup, the country was in disruption.*
3. (Business) a radical change in an industry, business strategy, etc., especially involving the introduction of a new product or service that creates a new market.

I think the definition you're looking for is the 3rd one.  For example, Uber and Lyft are two startups which have **disrupted** the traditional taxi industry.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it accurately represents the formal sense of the business meaning of _disrupt_. But as Lamar Latrell points out in a comment above, _disrupt_ is now used by MBA types as an empty buzzword with a contemporary cachet and no real meaning, much as _innovative_ was ten years ago and _think outside the box_ ten years before that. The people who use it are, by and large, unimaginative herd thinkers, people who have never disrupted anything, never had an innovative idea, and never thought outside the narrow box of business conventionality they inhabit.